# network interface configuration file on Centos7

Tags: centos, centos7

I have added one more NIC on my CentOS 7 virtual machine. But I dont see this `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ensxxx` file for newly added NIC, I have restarted network services, rebooted server, but still no config file showing.

Just wondering that if I have to manually create this config file? or something else has to be done?

Comment: The device will be available using Network Manager, either gui or cli. It is then up to you to provide the network configuration, by default the interface will be connected in L2 level, which means up and running but without any configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Configuration files creates only during install. If you add new NIC after install, you should create file manually or configure NIC trough Network Manager, it would create file.